# Is there a way to capture hyperspectral images using cell phone camera?

Tags: camera, android-camera

I know that many cell phone cameras support a wider spectral range than just the visible light. Also, some of them can capture raw images.
Is there a way to capture multispectral or [hyperspectral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging) images using cell phones?

Comment: https://www.eigenimaging.com/pages/eigencam-app

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. Hyperspectral sensors are extremely expensive and won't be in cell phones for the foreseeable future.

Supporting a wider spectral range is one element that makes hyerspectral sensors particular, however the main difference is to be able to 'cut' the spectrum into hundreds (or thousands) of channels of a few nm wide, which allows to perform spectroscopy. This requires special hardware, this capacity is independent to that of sensing infrared/ultraviolet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out http://www.specim.fi/worlds-first-mobile-hyperspectral-camera-revealed/. Though it may not be that robust compared to a traditional hyperspectral camera, it does support certain functionalities.

Comment: The Specim device is a hyperspectral camera, yes, and quite impressive at that. It's not a cell phone camera though, nor does it fit into a normal size pocket.